# What postgres connection string on AWS docker multicontainer app?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, docker, devops

What Postgres connection string should I use if I run a docker multicontainer app via `Dockerrun.aws.js` on *AWS*?

I have a Node.JS/Postgres/docker web-application. Postgres runs in its own container and so does the app. Locally, the app runs ok. When I deploy it to *AWS* via *ECR* and *BeanStalk*, the application successfully deploys and runs, but the web-app doesn't connect to Postgres.

In `docker-compose.yaml`, the host in the connection string is the name of the container (in my case it would be *db*). That doesn't work with *AWS*. Neither does `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

Here is my `Dockerrun.aws.js`:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "volumes": [
    {
      "name": "db-data",
      "host": {
        "sourcePath": "/data/db"
      }
    }
  ],
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "db",
      "image": "db_image_name",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 128,
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "POSTGRES_USER",
          "value": "postgres"
        },
        {
          "name": "POSTGRES_PASSWORD",
          "value": "password"
        },
        {
          "name": "PGDATA",
          "value": "/data/db/pgdata"
        }
      ],
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 5432,
          "containerPort": 5432
        }
      ],
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "sourceVolume": "db-data",
          "containerPath": "/data/db"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "app",
      "image": "app_image_name",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 128,
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "NODE_ENV",
          "value": "production"
        },
        {
          "name": "DB_HOST",
          "value": "db"
        },
        {
          "name": "DB_PORT",
          "value": "5432"
        },
        {
          "name": "DB_PASSWORD",
          "value": "password"
        }
      ],
      "links": [
        "db"
      ],
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 80,
          "containerPort": 3000
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

What should I put in the environment variable **DB_HOST**? (*DB_HOST* together with *DB_PORT* are used by the app to construct the connection string.) Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi. How are you connecting from nodejs to postgres? Do you have two Dockerrun.aws.json one for nodejs and other for mongo?

Comment: @JRichardsz, I don't use mongo at all – I work with SQL directly. So the app just sends queries directly (packages pg and pg-promise).

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I meant postgres instead mongo. Do you have two Dockerrun.aws.json one for nodejs and other for postgress? Are you isgon EC2 for nodejs and RDS for postgress?

Comment: Nope, just this single Dockerrun.aws.js that I posted in the question.

Comment: Amazon BeanStalk uses EC2 & RDS in background. Are you able to view the EC2 (nodejs) and the RDS (postgress) instances in your aws dashboard?

Comment: I don't use RDS – I use a postgres docker image with a mounted volume. But yeah, there are two green instances running in th EC2 dashboard. Which I don't really understand, I'd expect one, with docker running in it. I will have to dive deeper into the docs, I guess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187136/discussion-between-jrichardsz-and-adam-libusa).

Answer (score 0):

Beanstalk and Dockerrun.aws.json format offer you a possibility to link containers from the same definition file with the following syntax:

`"links": ["some-name"]`

In your case you can add a link to `"db"` and postgres will be available in your app container under `db`. You don't even need to map container ports if you don't want to expose your postgres container to the world.

You can see an example in use in following docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_v2config.html#create_deploy_docker_v2config_dockerrun

Comment: I had it there (from my *Dockerrun.aws.json*: `"links": ["db"]`). It didn't help.